# Android Contact Tracing API documentation

Tags: android, ios, contact-tracing-api

do you know any good documentation of Android contact tracing API that Google and iOS jointly worked on? I found one

https://blog.google/documents/55/Android_Contact_Tracing_API.pdf

But the documentation does not make any sense to me.

Do you guys know link of any good doc?

Comment: All of the information is [here](https://www.google.com/covid19/exposurenotifications/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try out this [reference application](https://github.com/google/exposure-notifications-android) Google released.  You can run it, but **you won't be able to enable exposure notifications or call the other APIs** unless your account has been authorized by Google as associated with a public health authority.

**If you are not working for an authorized public health authority, you can still write code** to use Exposure Notification transmissions, but not using the custom APIs.  [Read here for how you can do that](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/04/24/hacking-with-contact-tracing-beacons)

Comment: Rather than using Google API ,  I ended up using your library for my project. But there is a challenge. I am using the library for scanning and broadcasting in the foreground. It worked for sometime, when I left my phone. But after a while (my phone idle for long period) my external detector was unable to detect which means my phone stopped transmitting. But as my app running in foreground, the scanning and transmission should go on forever isn't it? I am using scan between time 10000 and scan period as 1100.

Comment: gist link https://gist.github.com/epsi95/a0c49c065494d4399f3e20999b7e5059

Comment: Happy to answer this if you create a new question.  No room to answer in comments.